# Stop AJAX complete callback from undoing a change made in error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a button to have a certain state, but the `complete` callback from jQuery AJAX is overridding the button. What's the best way aroudn this situation? Here's a demo of what I'm trying to do.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
btn.disabled = true;
btn.innerHTML = 'Sending...';

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'https://ip.jsontest.com/',
 success: function(data, evt){
     //if(evt === 'nocontent'){
             btn.disabled = true;
                btn.innerHTML = 'No more content';
            //}
 },
 error: function(data){
 },
 complete: function(){
     btn.disabled = false;
            btn.innerHTML = 'Send'
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Send
</button>
```

Comment: No. The point of `complete` is that it is the last thing to happen after an AJAX request. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My specific use case at the moment is the button that triggers the AJAX is disabled before the call, and I'm removing the disable in `complete`, however, in `error` there's a certain condition that means I want it to remain disabled. The `complete` callback firing last means currently I can't do it using just the AJAX callbacks.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. Read this link and consider editing your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TomHart The `complete` function receive 2 arguments, the second being the status. You can use a condition in the `complete` callback. [See `complete` description](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: @amflare I've editing my question, does it fit a bit better now?

Comment: Yes. So to confirm, you want the button to disable during the request, then enable once it's done unless a specific error is thrown?

Comment: Yeah exactly, specifically keep toggling disabled/enabled, until the server response 204 No Content, then it want's to stay disabled.